# 32-bit docker image - compiled binary appears as 64bit

Tags: c++, bash, docker, dockerfile, protoc

Im trying to create a 32bit docker image, that has Googles gRPC on it.

I have created the Dockerfile extending from:

```
FROM  i386/ubuntu:17.04
```

I am able to compile both gRPC and Proto Buffers, however, when I try to use protoc I get `bash: /usr/local/bin/protoc: No such file or directory`.

When I run `file`, I see that the assembly is seen as 64bit.

```
file /usr/local/bin/protoc          
/usr/local/bin/protoc: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=e87bf6eb1c507bb7f65f3c7687df6a3b41b563be, stripped
```

My question, therefore, is how to write and build a docker image that is actually 32bit. When I run `uname -m` or `arch` in the container I get `x86_64`, but `dpkg --print-architecture` shows `i386` so it would seem that it's not actually a 32bit image.

Comment: Note: the "No such file or directory" refers to the ELF INTERP: `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`

Comment: You can fix the `uname` issue using `setarch(8)` ... how are you compiling? Remember gcc doesn't care about `uname` *or* about `dpkg`, only what it was configured as. Perhaps you're looking for `-m32`?

Comment: Ok. Thanks. When compiling Proto Buffers, where do I use the `-m32` arg?

Comment: `./configure CC='gcc -m32' CXX='g++ -m32'`